# How to catch event win.setContentProtection() function triggered ElectronJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, macos, electron

In this example I am using win.setContentProtection(true)

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

function createWindow() {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    })

    win.setContentProtection(true)


}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})


app.on('activate', () => {
    console.log('I am active')
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow()
    }
})
```

when screen capture application start window disappear and when it close window appear again.
But I want to catch event when application detect screen capture and hide application.

Here is the doc link: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetcontentprotectionenable-macos-windows

if it is not possible I want an alternative JavaScript solution like using
https://github.com/waitingsong/node-win32-api

Windows API doc link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity

> Anyone here who can help me?